# JSTL Treat String as Expression Language

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, jstl, el

I have a Teacher bean which contains the name format of how they wanted to see their students' name. I'm accessing the string using EL as shown below. The teacher was already set in the request.

```
<c:out value="${requestScope.teacher.nameFormat}"/>
```

The value of the name format was an expression language as shown below.

```
1. ${student.lastName}, ${student.firstName}
2. ${student.lastName}, ${student.firstName.substring(0,1)}
```

I want the student name to be displayed using the name format selected by the teacher.

```
1. Doe, John
2. Doe, J.
```

But the result I'm getting right now is the name format itself.

```
1. ${student.lastName}, ${student.firstName}
2. ${student.lastName}, ${student.firstName.substring(0,1)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a method inside your domain

```
class Person{

  public String getPrettyName(){
    //operate and return
  }
}
```

and on JSTL

```
<c:out value="${requestScope.teacher.prettyName}"/>
```

or

```
${requestScope.teacher.lastName}, ${fn:substring(requestScope.teacher.firstName, 0, 1)}
```

Comment: Hi Jigar Joshi, thanks for the reply. I actually have a teacher bean in the request. That's why I'm accessing it as shown in the question. But like I said its returning the string itself.

Comment: yes I am saying that if you modify your Bean class to include this method and call it this way and handle substring portion in java code it would be way easier

Comment: I really want the string to be treated as EL to display the formatted student name. I will try your suggestion if there is no other way. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why fn: ? it is not at all required to achieve what OP has asked.

Comment: @Shailesh where does it say ?

Comment: I don't have any reference but I am using all String related functions directly(Can't say about wrapper & other classes) and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `fn:`, all String related methods work directly as given below:

Use:

```
<c:out value="${requestScope.teacher.lastName}"/>
<c:out value="${requestScope.teacher.firstName.substring(0,1)}"/>
```

It should work. Moreover if you are keeping requestScope, it will look for particular value to evaluate EL in that particular scope only. So make sure your teacher is available in request scope.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fn: suggestion. I updated the question to make my real problem clearer.

Comment: But where are values set for student firstName & lastName? Post the code related to your Teacher class, I want to know whether Teacher Class have any field related to student? Or how you will get student related firstName & lastName?

Comment: A class has a teacher, then the students belong to a class. There was a CLASS_STUDENT table which contains the mapping of the student to the class. I learned that what I'm trying to achieve is impossible. That's why as suggested by Jigar Joshi I did the formatting in Java.

Comment: As you have accepted one of the answer, so has your problem been solved, Or as per your comment, shall I need to put efforts to understand it and try to provide any working solution?

Comment: My problem was already solved. I did the formatting in Java. Thanks.